# Search by value to all Firestore collection and subcollections with admin-sdk in Python

Tags: python, database, api, google-cloud-firestore, google-admin-sdk

I'm making some APIs that among many things are able to retrieve the respective document via a value.
My data structure is as follows

```
Schools (collection) -> Lombardy (doc) -> Milan (collection) -> Milan (doc) - School Test1 (collection) -> 0 (doc) -> document
```

In the school document there is the following information:

```
address: School address 1
INFORMATICS {
    4A INF: "GA24HJ"
}
```

My goal is to retrieve the name of the school (`School Test1`) and the `address` using the code GA24HJ.
My code:

```
firestore = firestore.client()

collections = firestore.collections()
        for doc in collections.stream():
            print(f'{doc.id} => {doc.to_dict()}')
```

Result:

```
Lombardy => {}
```

I want to clarify that I have not found anything useful online and that I am using Python and the admin sdk.

Answer (score 0):

According to the document structure you shared, there is no "School name". Assuming this is an error and you actually have something like this,

```
{
    "name": "School Test1"
    "address": "School address 1"
    "INFORMATICS": {
        "4A INF": "GA24HJ"
    }
}
```

you can use dot notation to query by nested fields inside map fields:

```
docs = firestore
.collection('Schools')
.where('INFORMATICS.`4A INF`', '==', 'GA24HJ')
.stream()

for doc in docs:
    my_school = doc.to_dict()
    print(my_school['name'])
```

Note that the use of CollectionRef `stream()` is prefered to `get()`